# If regularexpressionvalidator returns false launch method in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, email

I have a widget for a newsletter in which i use the RegularExpressionValidator to check if the email input is valid. My codebehind is a method that opens an smtp connection and sends an email. 
My .aspx looks like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control newsmail"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator style="position:absolute; margin-top:50px; margin-left:58px;" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid E-mail" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-success submit" OnClick="submit_Click1" />
```

and my codebehind has the following method:

```
protected void submit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
.... 
}
```

Obviously as it is now, it will try to send the email whether the e-mail is valid or not. Therefore im looking for some kind of conditional expression that takes the RegEx into consideration before it completes the method and sends the e-mail.

I know its possible to do it all in C#, but im fairly new to C#, so this looked like the easiest workaround at this point.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can i make my method play together with the regularexpressionvalidator, so that it only sends the email if the regEx doesn't catch an invalid e-mail address

Comment: @NineBerry but i didn't specify anything in my code behind about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validators in the ASP.net page can already work as JavaScript in the Browser. When you enable this functionality and the user's browser has JavaScript enabled, then your `submit_Click1` method will not even be executed when there is invalid data in the input controls.

If you disable the validators to work at the client side or the user's browser does not have JavaScript enabled, you should check in the code behind that all the validators successfully validated the user input. You can do that by checking the `isValid` property of the page:

```
protected void submit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page.IsValid)
    {
        // All Validators Passed -> Do something
    }
    else
    {
        // Some invalid data, do nothing
    }
}
```